# Why does text change size when a separate string is made longer?

Tags: html, css

See the two simple web pages below.
Only difference in them is the length of the text that starts: "This is a very".
However, look at the difference in how they render on a mobile device.
The screenshots shown are from developer tools in Chrome, but I get same results on my Anrdroid and Kindle (only two physical devices I have).
Why don't the two pages render the text the same size?
FYI am using the two files for illustrative purposes.
I can get bigger text from Fontsize.html by editing and adding text to it.
Baffled.

Fontsize.html

```
<html>
<body>

<span  style="font-family:'Open Sans';font-size:20pt">SAMPLE TEXT - 20pt</span>

      <br><br>This is a very long line that may well force it into the larger font but we cant be sure can we

</body>
</html>
```

FontSizeLarger.html

```
<html>
<body>

<span  style="font-family:'Open Sans';font-size:20pt">SAMPLE TEXT - 20pt</span>

      <br><br>This is a very long line that may well force it into the larger font but we cant be sure can we
      This is a very long line that may well force it into the larger font but we cant be sure can we
      This is a very long line that may well force it into the larger font but we cant be sure can we

</body>
</html>
```

Pages Rendered
[image]

Comment: I think this is the browser issue, every browser has its own styles. I am providing you a link this may help you https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000779.htm

Comment: I checked your 2 codes, and it's normal. Can you check zoom percent in chrome is 100% on fontsize.html? Press CTRL + 0 to reset zoom percent to 100%.

Comment: Pages are zoomed the same (default) in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Researched and found answer.
Mobile browsers, including Chrome, evidently have their own heuristics for adjusting text size that override applied styles in some cases.  The idea is that when mobile was new, many web sites rendered poorly on mobile devices when their own styling was applied. This was because they were designed for the desktop. To help w/this, mobile browsers sometimes adjust text size on their own, hoping to make such sites more readable.
When a site is designed w/a "mobile first" mindset, this adjustment is not needed.  In fact, it can get in the way as in my case.
Solution is to turn it off w/below CSS or similar.
Thanks

```
html,body {
        text-size-adjust: none;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
        -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
        -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> you should use `rem` , `em` , instead of `pt`. I think it depends on the screen resolution so the font gets adjust according to res.
> You can know more about units [here](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html)